# Как добавить класc в лист? Web c#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Мне нужно написать Hadler для приложения.(Гостевая книга). У меня есть класс Message, в котором есть эти поля:

```
       using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestGuestbook.Data
{
    [Guid("6D07675D-1F17-482D-A576-2DDBE5C8C7DF")]
    [CJE.Serializable(CJE.Serializable.Politics.AllExceptExcluded)]
    public class Message : CJE.ISerializable
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public IList<Data.Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public int CommentsCount { get; set; }
        public double Rating { get; set; }

    }
}
```

В каждое собщение вложен коментарий(comments). Как добавить в этот лист созданный комментарий? Вот поля comment:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestGuestbook.Data
{
    [CJE.Serializable(CJE.Serializable.Politics.AllExceptExcluded)]
    [Guid("295adfa6-c227-435c-92b9-a7ae014a2604")]
    public class Comment : CJE.ISerializable
    {
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что именно не получается, покажите код, который не работает.